# how to query summary crosstab

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to do crosstab in mysql, I can make by month and rows summary. 
but I want to do summary by month. Any idea how I can modify my query?

My Table:
Table1

```
jobid    jobtype    jobcomplete
14001      1        2014-01-05
14002      1        2014-01-07
14003      1        2014-02-01
14004      2        2014-01-05
14005      3        2014-02-08
14006      1        2014-03-05
14007      1        2014-04-05
14008      1        2014-05-05
14009      1        2014-06-05
14010      1        2014-07-05
14011      1        2014-08-05
14012      1        2014-09-05
14013      1        2014-10-05
14014      1        2014-11-05
14015      1        2014-12-05
14016      2        2014-12-05
```

Table2

```
jobtype    desc
  1        hardware
  2        software
  3        network
```

Using cross tab:

```
Select t2.desc as test,sum(IF(Month(t1.jobcomplete)=1,1,0)) AS JAN,
sum(IF(Month(t1.jobcomplete)=2,1,0)) AS FAB,
sum(IF(Month(t1.jobcomplete)=3,1,0)) AS MAR,
sum(IF(Month(t1.jobcomplete)=4,1,0)) AS APR,
sum(IF(Month(t1.jobcomplete)=5,1,0)) AS MAY,
sum(IF(Month(t1.jobcomplete)=6,1,0)) AS JUN,
sum(IF(Month(t1.jobcomplete)=7,1,0)) AS JUL,
sum(IF(Month(t1.jobcomplete)=8,1,0)) AS AUG,
sum(IF(Month(t1.jobcomplete)=9,1,0)) AS SEP,
sum(IF(Month(t1.jobcomplete)=10,1,0)) AS OCT,
sum(IF(Month(t1.jobcomplete)=11,1,0)) AS NOV,
sum(IF(Month(t1.jobcomplete)=12,1,0)) AS DEC,
Count(t1.job_complete) as Total
FROM table1 as t1 INNER JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.jobtype=t2.jobtype GROUP BY t1.jobtype
```

Which gives me this:

```
   test      JAN  FAB  MAR  APR  MAY  JUN  JUL  AUG  SEP OCT  NOV  DEC  Total  
 hardware     2    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1   1    1    1    13
 software     1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   0    0    1     2
 network      0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   0    0    0     1
```

I Want This Result:

```
    test      JAN  FAB  MAR  APR  MAY  JUN  JUL  AUG  SEP OCT  NOV  DEC  Total  
   hardware     2    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1   1    1    1    13
   software     1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   0    0    1     2
   network      0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   0    0    0     1
   TOTAL        2    2    1    1    1    1    1    1    1   1    1    2    16
```

Thank you very much and Sorry for my bad English. I'm not good at English.

Comment: Add a `UNION` -> `UNION Select 'TOTAL' as test,sum(IF(Month(t1.jobcomplete)=1,1,0)) AS JAN, ... FROM table1 as t1`?

Comment: Wow thanks @Sean. I can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can do it. Thank @Sean for answer.

```
(Select t2.desc as test,sum(IF(Month(t1.jobcomplete)=1,1,0)) AS JAN,
sum(IF(Month(t1.jobcomplete)=2,1,0)) AS FAB,
sum(IF(Month(t1.jobcomplete)=3,1,0)) AS MAR,
sum(IF(Month(t1.jobcomplete)=4,1,0)) AS APR,
sum(IF(Month(t1.jobcomplete)=5,1,0)) AS MAY,
sum(IF(Month(t1.jobcomplete)=6,1,0)) AS JUN,
sum(IF(Month(t1.jobcomplete)=7,1,0)) AS JUL,
sum(IF(Month(t1.jobcomplete)=8,1,0)) AS AUG,
sum(IF(Month(t1.jobcomplete)=9,1,0)) AS SEP,
sum(IF(Month(t1.jobcomplete)=10,1,0)) AS OCT,
sum(IF(Month(t1.jobcomplete)=11,1,0)) AS NOV,
sum(IF(Month(t1.jobcomplete)=12,1,0)) AS DEC,
Count(t1.job_complete) as Total
FROM table1 as t1 INNER JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.jobtype=t2.jobtype GROUP BY t1.jobtype)
UNION
(Select 'TOTAL' As TOTAL,sum(IF(Month(t1.jobcomplete)=1,1,0)) AS JAN,
sum(IF(Month(t1.jobcomplete)=2,1,0)) AS FAB,
sum(IF(Month(t1.jobcomplete)=3,1,0)) AS MAR,
sum(IF(Month(t1.jobcomplete)=4,1,0)) AS APR,
sum(IF(Month(t1.jobcomplete)=5,1,0)) AS MAY,
sum(IF(Month(t1.jobcomplete)=6,1,0)) AS JUN,
sum(IF(Month(t1.jobcomplete)=7,1,0)) AS JUL,
sum(IF(Month(t1.jobcomplete)=8,1,0)) AS AUG,
sum(IF(Month(t1.jobcomplete)=9,1,0)) AS SEP,
sum(IF(Month(t1.jobcomplete)=10,1,0)) AS OCT,
sum(IF(Month(t1.jobcomplete)=11,1,0)) AS NOV,
sum(IF(Month(t1.jobcomplete)=12,1,0)) AS DEC,
Count(t1.job_complete) as Total
FROM table1 as t1 )
```